# Console problems using "Git Bash"

Tags: windows, directory, console, git-bash, mkdir

I am using Git Bash to practice Unix commands.

What does the following line mean as soon as I open the console?
palex02@LAPTOP-TO2B6AA MINDF64

Also, when I try to use the ls Desktop command I don't see any files or directories. Also with mkdir (always on the Dsktop) I do not see the folder created (but if I go to the Desktop folder I see that it has been created).

This is the path I use:

**~/Desktop**

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen that happen when someone is using OneDrive, and they're backing up the desktop.

If that is the cause of your situation, `C:\Users\<username>\Desktop` exists but its contents were moved. The typical methods of accessing Windows Desktop are now using a different folder called "Desktop" in the OneDrive controlled folder.That would be `C:\Users\<username>\OneDrive\Desktop` or `C:\Users\<username>\OneDrive - <your business name>\Desktop`.

In such cases, it's common for the same kind of change to apply to "`Documents`" and "`Pictures`" folders, but they're each optional.